# setState not re-rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

I have looked at previous answers but cannot find a solution.
My state contains a deck of "color cards":

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.allCards = ['#fca7f3 ', 'white', ' #6da740  ','  #f6faba  ', ' #ccc5c1 ', '  #f7791f  ', ' #575657 ', ' #03faf5 ', ' #13afdb ', ' #7509e2 ', ' #63522e ', ' #d809e2 ', '#060606', '#fd2f03',' #effa17 ',' #33fb2d ']
    this.state = {currentDeck: [' #ccc5c1 ', '  #f7791f  ', ' #575657 ', ' #03faf5 ',]}
  }
```

This is updated with this function:

```
   changeDifficulty = (e) => {
    let newDeck = []
    let howManyCards = e.target.value // this decides difficulty level
    for (let i = 0; i < howManyCards; i++) {
      newDeck.push(this.allCards[i])
    }
    this.setState({currentDeck: newDeck}) 
  }
```

The state is successfully updating, however, the component below is not re-rendering after the first render:

```
<Game deck={this.state.currentDeck} />
```

So the number of cards on the screen remains the same as the default setting.

If I console.log `newDeck` before setting state, it shows the following, first after clicking Medium button, then after Hard.

```
Array(8) [ "#fca7f3 ", "white", " #6da740  ", "  #f6faba  ", " #ccc5c1 ", "  #f7791f  ", " #575657 ", " #03faf5 " ]
Array(12) [ "#fca7f3 ", "white", " #6da740  ", "  #f6faba  ", " #ccc5c1 ", "  #f7791f  ", " #575657 ", " #03faf5 ", " #13afdb ", " #7509e2 ", … ]
```

Comment: I dont see any issue here - may be worth creating a runnable snippet either here or jsfiddle

Comment: also, you can simplify this using `slice` - `changeDifficulty = () => { this.setState({ currentDeck: this.allCards.slice(0, Number(e.target.value))})}`. I prefer to use array operators that return new arrays, like `slice`, `map`, `filter` etc rather than rely on created new arrays and pushing to them, it guarantees you haven't missed created a new array first and wondering why state is not updating

Comment: Trying to figure out jsfiddle as we speak. And thanks for the slice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your array reference is not updated in state when you write this,

```
 this.setState({currentDeck: newDeck})
```

As the reference is not updated react renderer doesn't know about the update. What you need to do is create a new array and push that in state like this,

```
 this.setState({currentDeck: [...newDeck]})
```

Comment: it is... there is a new array created first - `let newDeck = []`

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part. In that case I don't see any issue with the given code. can you console log newDeck before updating the state and add some more related code in the post?

Comment: @sabbir.alam I just added the console.log, it really doesn't show any issues though. Even when I console.log the state using other functions it also shows that it's updated. It just refuses to re-render the <Game /> component